# Internet Lead Capture Web form to Custom Entity in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4 Online

Tags: dynamics-crm, lead, dynamics-crm-online

I have CRM 4 Online account and am very new to dynamics CRM. I have to create a webpage where customer can send testimonials and I want to push those into a custom entity called testimonials. I cannot figure out a way to change the Internet Lead Capture to make it put data received into a custom entity directly. Any help is greatly appreciated. Right now I am tight on budget and cannot buy Web2CRM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new user call Testimonials
Create a new tab on the Lead Form called Testimonials and put one new lead field on that tab call Testimonials with a large box (space)

Create your landing page with the field Testimonials for customers to submit
Once the internet leads arrive, simply assign them to the new user that you created name 'Testimonials"

To view all testimonial, go to leads and save a view showing all leads owned by 'Testimonial"